# checking maximum time taken by specific processes in BIDS SSIS packages

Tags: bids

is there a way to check maximum time taken by specific processes in BIDS SSIS packages while debugging, so we can optimize the those processes

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i checked the progress report but the main issue is there are more than 60 process are linked in one ssis package, i googled is there any smoother way to check the processing time for all processes in package, and which is taking maximum time in it